# Voting not done with Advanced Poll on Views page for Zen sub theme

Tags: 7, theming, polls

I am using the Views Infinity Scroll and the Views modules. I am using Advanced Poll for the polls. I tried to list all the Advanced poll content types. 
The voting for the polls is done quite good in the Bartik theme. It is not working with the Zen theme and the Bootstrap theme. I have checked the scripts loading with the page. All is well with that.

Can anyone help with it?

Comment: I found that the Ajax event is not triggering on the Views page using the zen sub theme, while it is working perfectly on its page using the same zen sub theme.

Comment: It is working perfectly with default Drupal themes.